# stop document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunctionResume, false);
function yourCallbackFunctionResume()
{
      document.removeEventListener("resume", function(){});
      alert("Resume off");
}
```

still using alert again and again when application resumes.WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the removeEventListener() call.

```
document.removeEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction);
```

**Edit 1:**
Your need to change your code as shown below.

```
function yourCallbackFunctionResume()
{
      document.removeEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunctionResume);
      alert("Resume off");
}
```

Comment: not working,still using the document.addEventListener

Comment: can you explain what is not working. What do you mean by still using document.addEventListener?

Comment: please see my edited answer. The function will not be called the next time the resume event fires.

Comment: i want to stop this document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunctionResume, false);

Comment: if i use this it will go into loop if i am not wrong document.removeEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunctionResume);

Comment: It will not go into a loop. It is making a call to disconnect the function from the event. It(yourCallbackFunctionResume function) does not get called/executed. Try it and let me know..=